# Angular pass child data to view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a page that return user data from API and user data has child array named `store` and I cannot get data of this child array to my view it returns `undefined`

## Code

```
export class TokoPage implements OnInit {

  store= null;
  token: any;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private storage: NativeStorage,
  ) {
    this.storage.getItem('token').then((token) => {
      this.token = token;
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.user().subscribe((user) => {
      console.log('auth user', user);
      console.log('1', user['sotre']); //undefined
    });
  }
}
```

`View`

```
{{store.name}}
```

`returned data`

[image: one]

Any idea?

## Update

`JSON.stringify(user)` results

```
{
    "success":[
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"xxxxx",
            "username":"admin",
            "email":"xxxxx",
            "phone":"xxxxx",
            "avatar":null,"
            coins":0,
            "type":"admin",
            "email_verified_at":"2019-08-13 14:08:09",
            "created_at":"2019-08-13 14:08:09",
            "updated_at":"2019-08-13 14:08:09",
            "products":[{xxxxxxx}],
            "addresses":[],
            "wishlist":[],
            "orders":[],
            "store":{
                "id":1,
                "name":"xxxxx",
                "url":"xxxxx",
                "logo":null,
                "banner":null,
                "description":"xxxxx",
                "kota_id":xxxxx,
                "province_id":xxxxx,
                "province":"xxxxx",
                "kota":"xxxxx",
                "address":"xxxxx",
                "phone":"xxxxx",
                "user_id":1,
                "active":"yes",
                "verified":"yes",
                "best_seller":"yes",
                "created_at":"2019-08-13 14:08:09",
                "updated_at":"2019-08-15 09:17:40"
            },
            "rating":[]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: typo mate -> `console.log('1', user['store']);`

Comment: still undefined

Comment: @NidhinJoseph could be because `success` is array? I mean do i need to loop it first?!

Comment: yep, i have answered it, its an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo

```
console.log('1', user['store']);
```

Secondly, you are accessing it the wrong way, `success` is an array

```
this.authService.user().subscribe((user: any) => {
  console.log('auth user', user.success[0]['store']);
});
```

```js
let user = {
  "success": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xxxxx",
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "xxxxx",
    "phone": "xxxxx",
    "avatar": "null",
    "coins": 0,
    "type": "admin",
    "email_verified_at": "2019-08-13 14:08:09",
    "created_at": "2019-08-13 14:08:09",
    "updated_at": "2019-08-13 14:08:09",
    "products": [],
    "addresses": [],
    "wishlist": [],
    "orders": [],
    "store": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "xxxxx",
      "url": "xxxxx",
      "logo": null,
      "banner": null,
      "description": "xxxxx",
      "kota_id": "xxxxx",
      "province_id": "xxxxx",
      "province": "xxxxx",
      "kota": "xxxxx",
      "address": "xxxxx",
      "phone": "xxxxx",
      "user_id": 1,
      "active": "yes",
      "verified": "yes",
      "best_seller": "yes",
      "created_at": "2019-08-13 14:08:09",
      "updated_at": "2019-08-15 09:17:40"
    },
    "rating": []
  }]
};
console.log(user.success[0]['store']);
```

Comment: When i use `user[0]['store']` it return `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined`

Comment: have edited, your `success` is an array inside the `user` object. Since i don't have your json, i think this is the case

Comment: `return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus);`

Comment: did you try `user.success[0]['store']` ??

Comment: I did it gets data but when i'm serving my code it returns error `[ng] ERROR in src/app/pages/toko/toko.page.ts(28,16): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'User'.
[ng] src/app/pages/toko/toko.page.ts(29,27): error TS2339: Property 'success' does not exist on type 'User'.
[ng]`

Comment: can you do a `JSON.stringify(user)` and paste the output here or in the OP?

Comment: the original post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198344/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-mafortis).